# ASP.NET MVC3 compile on request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

In previous technologies it was possible to have a compile-on-request behaviour. I'm looking to do the same thing on MVC3, whereas I can make changes to the source code and have it automatically compiled upon the next browser request. The current work-flow is to stop debugging a project, make the changes, and debug again, after which you have to navigate to the page you came from. I'd rather have it compile upon request to increase RAD. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVC does not support what you're looking for.  However, there is a different solution to your problem.  Configure the assembly to build 32-bit code, and turn on "Edit and Continue", then you can debug, make changes, it will compile on the fly and continue from where you left off.

Comment: Can you please link for a page that describes how to do all that steps?